# Python optimization with multiple and changing variables

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, solver

I'm new to Python and looking to find an optimized solution with a number of constraints, where those constraints are based on functions of the outputs.

First two constraints are straightforward:

1) `output1  +output2 + output3 = 1`

2) output1, output2, and output3 must all be >= 0

Last constraint needs functions of the outputs to be EQUAL:

3) `f(output1) == f(output2) == f(output3)`

In this case the function array is produced a matrix multiplication of the outputs:

```
F = cov.dot(array([output1,output2,output3]))*array([output1,output2,output3])

f(output1) = F[0], f(output2) = F[1], f(output3) = F [2]
```

Hopefully I've described the problem clearly... Eventually I want to extend this to more outputs than 3.
What I have below gives me output values that don't appear to follow the constraints at all (gives me a negative value). I assume I'm entering the constraints wrong... or perhaps there is an easier way to do this with `np.linalg.solve`?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

cov=np.array([0.04,0.0015,0.03,0.0015,0.0025,0.000625,0.03,0.000625,0.0625]).reshape(3,3)

weights=np.array([0.3,0.2,0.5])

def RC(w):
    return cov.dot(w)*w

riskcont = RC(weights)

def PV(riskcont):
    return np.sqrt(riskcont.sum())

portvol = PV(riskcont)    

def ERC(z):

    w1=z[0]
    w2=z[1]
    w3=z[2]
    #1) weights sum to 100%
    out=w1 +w2 +w3 -1
    #2) weights above zero
    out.append((w1*w2*w3)>0)
    #3) riskcont must all be equal
    out.append([riskcont[0] == riskcont[1] == riskcont[2]] #== riskcont(w4)))

    return out

z= fsolve(ERC,[1/3,1/3,1/3])
```

Comment: PS. line above that starts ``out.append([riskcont[0]== etc.`` is missing a ) at the end

Comment: I'm beginner too, but:, are you using python 2.7 ? If so 1/3 is integer division = 0

Comment: `out.append((w1*w2*w3)>0)` is at least one of your problems. All that line requires is that an even number of weights are negative. (i.e. (-1 * -1 * 1) = (1 * 1 * 1) )

Comment: Also, `riskcont` never changes in the script as run.

Comment: Using Python 3.5 (and Anaconda 4.1.1)

Yes it is a bit of a shortcut - couldnt find a way to put multiple conditions into one constraint... `w1&w2&w3 >=0` doesnt work either

Do you know a different way to do that?